# Compiling SystemVerilog DPI with Modelsim DE 10.6b on Ubuntu 64-bit 16.04

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-16.04, modelsim, system-verilog-dpi

I have Modelsim DE 10.6b installed on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 and  when I run Modelsim examples of SystemVerilog DPI, I get auto compile linking error shown below:

** Fatal: ** Fatal: (vsim-3828) Could not link 'vsim_auto_compile.so': cmd = '/opt/modelsim_dlx/gcc-5.3.0-linux/bin/gcc -shared -fPIC -m32 -B/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -o "/tmp/shahin@shahin-Z400_dpi_2433/linuxpe_gcc-5.3.0/vsim_auto_compile.so" /opt/modelsim_dlx/examples/systemverilog/dpi/checkpoint/work/_dpi/auto_compile@/linuxpe_gcc-5.3.0/*.o

Can anyone please help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have installed the 32-bit version of Modelsim on 64-bit Ubuntu. Try installing the 64-version. Otherwise see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit) for running 32-bit applications on 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So far as I know, Modelsim only offers 32-bit version for linux. General features of Modelsim work, but the DPI does not work and that's because of gcc linking issue.

Comment: I already have those 32-bit libraries installed for other applications, but that did not help for DPI in ModelSim

Comment: I have heard from Mentor support, that they do NOT support Ubuntu, only Centos and SUSE. So there might be some other tweaks that fix this.

Comment: Modelsim offers both 32-bit and 64-bit for Linux. Correct that Ubuntu is not officially supported, but people have gotten it to work.

Comment: I am sorry. I noticed that I have already installed the 64-bit for linux. So still this is an issue. I was confused whether this is a 32-bit or 64-bit linux version, because one of the installation files, i.e. modelsim_dlx-linuxpe.mis only comes in 32-bit format or at the least the name implies.